# Does a foreach of an IQueryable-as-IEnumerable allow previously iterated objects to be GC'ed / reclaimed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, garbage-collection, entity-framework-6, ienumerable

Given, for example:

```
IEnumerable<LargeObject> Read(int x) {
    // Implicit IQueryable<LargeObject> -> IEnumerable<LargeObject>
    return ef6Context.LargeObjects.Where(o => o.ObjectType == x);
}

var largeObjects = Read(21281); // Returns "many" objects

// Only use/iteration of IEnumerable result
foreach (var o in largeObject) {
   // When processing the second item (and so on),
   // can the first (previous) "o" object be GC'ed?
   Process(o);
}
```

Are the 'large objects' that have processed on *previous loops* eligible for garbage reclamation?

Answer should cover any internal EF caching, as appropriate.

Comment: When you ran the code and checked to see if the objects were actually cleaned up, what did you find?

Comment: Related: this would require that the `IEnumerator.Reset()` implementation throw `NotSupportedException` (the documentation specifically says this is allowed)

Comment: @BenVoigt How so?  (I strongly expect that it *does* throw, because most iterators don't bother to support restarting, but nothing about this would *prevent* it from supporting it).

Comment: Unless you store them somehow, they can be gc'ed.

Comment: This does not depend on the foreach() but on whatever impelemtation is behind that IEnumerable<>. EF can track them, or not, as answered below. But `o.Id` makes this a poor example.

Comment: @Servy: I guess the question is whether "on previous loops" means "previous iterations of the loop" (then being able to use `Reset` to visit objects from previous iterations would be relevant) or "loops on previously returned `IEnumerable` objects", in which case it wouldn't.

Comment: @BenVoigt On previous loops of the same IEnumerable being iterated..? (The results of Read are only consumed in once foreach.)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Poor choice of example on my part. The collection returned is "many thousands of items". I've updated the code to remove the implicit "ID" notion.

Comment: @BenVoigt `Reset` wouldn't need to yield previously yielded items, an entirely sensible implementation would be for it to just re-query the data.

Comment: @user2864740: You're still being unclear.  When you talk about "previous loops" do you mean different values of `o` all taken from the same query?  Or that the whole query and `foreach` ran to completion, and now you do both query and `foreach` loop a second time?

Comment: @Servy: I believe rerunning the query would violate `IEnumerator` postconditions.  The documented contract is that changes to the collection cause attempts to enumerate further to fail.  You only get around that by having the result of the query call be a "snapshot" of the results at a single moment in time... and that snapshot has to stay consistent for repeated passes over the same `IEnumerator`.  One possible loophole is whether, in flyweight object pattern, enumeration can return new objects tied back to the same snapshotted list of rows.

Comment: @user2864740: Thanks, that makes the question clear.  A big part of your problem is that, although `foreach` is single-forward-pass only, it uses the `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerator<T>` interfaces to access the data, and those interfaces are not restricted to single pass, nor is any parameter passed in to distinguish.

Comment: @BenVoigt One possible use of an `IEnumerator` is to enumerate the items in a collection.  It's not the only use case.  There are many others, including, for example, iterating the requests of a database query, like is the case here.  In that context, there *is no* underlying collection.  There is nothing in the contract of `IEnumerator` that it always yield the same things when iterated repeatedly, or that whatever is used to generate the data can't change. Specific data sources (i.e. most .NET collections) say in their documentation that they'll error if the underlying collection is changed.

Comment: @Servy: [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) says that `IEnumerator` supports simple iteration over a collection.  The generic version both [says the same thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) and also **implements** the non-generic `IEnumerator`, so all postconditions still apply.  The term collection is being used loosely, perhaps, but the documented contract that iteration stops if the collection changes applies to all data sources whether or not you agree with calling them collections.

Comment: My question seems to be a similar ask (ultimately) of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918294/is-there-a-way-to-enforce-entity-framework-to-read-one-record-from-db-at-a-time

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, an `IEnumerable` *can* be used to iterate through a collection.  It can (and often is) used for all sorts of other things (like what it's being used for here, to access the results of a DB query, rather than a collection).  Since there *is* no collection, any statements about the collection being modified don't even make sense, since *there isn't one*.

Comment: @Servy: Arguing with the documentation is pointless.  "simple iterator over a collection" is not merely an example of what `IEnumerable` is good for, the entire interface is defined by how it accesses a collection.  If there is no collection, it does not even make sense to have an `IEnumerable`, because it will never be able to meet its postconditions.  In reality, the word "collection" is being used to mean a general sequence of values, and not specifically an object from the `System.Collections` namespace.  **Results from a database query qualify as a collection** in the broad sense.

Comment: @BenVoigt The *typical* use case of the interface is defined in that sense.  The use cases that *don't* involve iterating over a collection are certainly less common, but still not rare.  There are *lots* of examples (even examples of .NET provided sequences) that *aren't* examples of iterating over a collection (for example every single `IEnumerable returned from a LINQ query is not iterating over a collection, it represents executing a query).  The results of a database query (or the query itself) aren't (necessarily) collections, even in the general sense.

Comment: Also consider `IEnumerables` like, say `Enumerable.Range`, where there isn't even a data source; it's just yielding items that it is generating itself.  If you want to call up MS and tell them that they're constantly using `IEnumerator` wrong and that they're using it for all sorts of things that don't involve just iterating a collection, you can try.  I don't expect you'll get super far with that.

Comment: @Servy: No, that's contractual documentation, not an example.  And I tell you that `Enumerable.Range(...).GetEnumerator()` does return items which are members of a collection (if we were using pure mathematical vocabulary instead of computer science, we'd say "a sequence"), just not a collection object.  If you like, you can actually use the fact and order that the `IEnumerator` visits them as the definition of the sequence/collection.

Comment: @BenVoigt `IEnumerable` *is* a *sequence*, conceptually.  That's quite different from a collection.  And `IEnumerable` *is* a sequence (rather than having one, it *is* one).  But anyway, if you think that Microsoft has provided hundreds of implementations of `IEnumerable` that violate the contract that is required of them, again, you should submit bug reports for them, because apparently you think that a huge percentage of the framework's implementations violate it.

Comment: @Servy: Ok, now at least we agree that *sequence* is a correct term for what we're working with.  You appear to believe that Microsoft is incorrect to use "collection" when they talk about a sequence, I don't think it's really a problem.  But if you insist on saying "sequence", then just substitute "sequence" everywhere the postconditions say "collection", they'll still make sense.  And the point I made at the very beginning still applies -- either the sequence is a snapshot, in which case requerying at `IEnumerator.Reset` is not permitted, or it is live, in which case the `IEnumerator`

Comment: (continued) must, according to the documented contract, recognize and stop enumeration when the underlying sequence changes.

Comment: @BenVoigt But `IEnumerator` doesn't *have* a sequence; it doesn't *contain* one, it *is* one.  It's *output* is a sequence, not it's input.  The documentation just says that *one possible* implementation of an `IEnumerable` is to iterate over a collection.  It is in fact a very common thing for an `IEnumerable` to represent, and when one is writing such an `IEnumerable`, certain conventions exist.  Those conventions don't apply at all when you're writing a *different* type of `IEnumerable`, one that isn't just iterating over a collection.  This is an example of the latter, not the former.

Comment: @Servy: The documented behavior of `IEnumerable` members apply to *all* implementations of the interface.

Comment: @BenVoigt So then let me know how [that bug report goes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226259/does-a-foreach-of-an-iqueryable-as-ienumerable-allow-previously-iterated-objects?noredirect=1#comment79418896_46226259) when you inform MS that, according to you, a huge portion of `IEnumerable` implementations apparently don't follow your interpretation of the documented behavior.  Or you could instead recognize that the documentation itself doesn't actually mandate that and `IEnumerable` can only ever iterate over a collection, and simply lists that as *one possible [common] example*.

Comment: @Servy: Or, their documentation does mandate that `IEnumerable` iterates over a collection, but that mandate uses "collection" synonymously with "sequence", and in fact most of the enumerator implementations that don't work on .NET collection objects do nonetheless work on a conceptual sequence/collection, and the vast majority of them adhere to the postconditions as well.  And the postconditions are intended to apply to *all* implementations no matter what the sequence is, so returning from a different sequence after `Reset()` than before is simply not allowed.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's *possible* that MS intended for their documentation to say that `IEnumerable` *must* iterate over a collection, even though they never said that, and it's *possible* that they meant to say that they iterate over a sequence, instead of a collection, and it's *possible* that they provided hundreds of implementations that violate those same demands that you think they intended to say but never actually said. It's also possible that they didn't actually put any of those things in the documentation because they didn't actually want to require them, rather than because they forgot to.

Comment: The what the documentation *actually* says for `Reset` is that it should set the sequence to its initial position. It doesn't actually say that it's essential that it yield exact the same values that it initially yielded, even though you're claiming it says that.

Comment: The documentation does actually say what you claim I'm pulling out of thin air.  Direct quote: "All calls to Reset must result in the same state for the enumerator."

I'll remind you that you also said "IEnumerator doesn't have a sequence; it doesn't contain one, it *is* one."  Therefore, the only way to have `IEnumerator` in the same state is for the sequence to be unchanged.  If the sequence can't be reproduced, `Reset()` has to throw.

Comment: @BenVoigt For many sequences the output of the sequence *isn't dependant on state*.  For example, a sequence that prints out the current time every time a value is asked for *needs no state*, so you can ensure that all of the state is the same after resetting it, and yet it will yield different values.  The same is true in this specific case.  The state of the iterator is *the instructions for the query it is to execute*, so that can be maintained while the values that result can change.  The documentation *doesn't* say that if the sequence can't be reproduced that reset has to throw.

Comment: @servy: No, it's not.  The state of an iterator is *everything* that controls the returned values.  It probably does include member variables of the iterator, but in your example, it also includes (a) the computer clock, (b) the database content.  The documentation *does* say that `Reset()` throws if the sequence (collection) changes.

Comment: @BenVoigt A computer clock is not a collection.  A database is not a collection.  The documentation says that *if* the `IEnumerable` is backed by that collection, and that collection changes, it should throw.  Since there are *lots* of sequences that *aren't* backed by a collection, that statement doesn't apply to them, because it can't, because they have no backing collection that can change.  Again, you wishing that the documentation said something different than it actually does (namely that the returned values need to be equal after a reset) doesn't mean it actually says that.

Comment: @Servy: I didn't say that a computer clock is a collection.  I said it's part of the *state* of the enumerator which is a timestamp generator.  Database content (or a snapshot thereof) is part of the *state* of an enumerator which is a database cursor.  *state* and the returned *sequence* are not the same thing, but the *sequence* depends only on the *state*.

Comment: @BenVoigt A clock is not internal state of an enumerator, it's an external dependency.

Comment: @Servy: You're right that it is not "internal".  It is external, shared state, but it is part of the state in your example.

Comment: @BenVoigt So care to quote the section of the documentation that says if some external value that is not a part of the state of the iterator itself changes, that the iterator cannot be restarted?  Because reading the actual documentation it just says that resetting should set the position of the iterator to before the first item in the sequence.  I couldn't find the part about not being allowed to have external dependencies that change.

Comment: @Servy: Only state which affects the sequence.  The PC clock is part of the external state for every iterator, but most don't utilize it in generating outputs.  The requirement you seem to be unable to find is [right here](http://untrusted.markkit.net/untrusted/https___msdn.microsoft.com_en-us_library_system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v_vs.110).aspx.html?s=hfrbt4bl7qoas7ggas5d588mb5#)

Comment: None of those constraints are violated.  There is no underlying collection, so it is not modified, the enumerators internal state is all reset (because it has none).  So you seem to be unable to point to a section of the documentation that states that iterators cannot have external dependencies that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework keeps all entities retrieved from the database in the context so they will not be collected after iteration. This is done in order to track changes. You cand disable this feature by calling `AsNoTracking` on your query before execution ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx)). Doing so `SaveChanges` will not persistent any changes made to these entities.

As for the question on weather the object is released after every iteration, the answer is yes. I created a simple demo that ilustrates this by adding logging code in the constructor and destructor and added an explicit GC call. The destructor was called after every iteration.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            //for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            //{
            //    db.Enta.Add(new Entity());

            //}
            //db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var e in db.Enta.AsNoTracking())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Id);
                GC.Collect();
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ctor");

    }

    ~Entity()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("destructor");
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Enta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added `AsNoTracking()` - if this is done, is the IEnumerable-iterator itself "able" to keep previously iterated objects alive?

Comment: Objects from the iteration variable will follow the same rules as any other.Net objects, they will be alive as long as you have a reference to them.

Comment: Then the question is: does the IEnumerable implementation of IQueryable of EF6 maintain these references during iteration (with tracking OFF)? Or does simply "having" the IEnumerable prevent reclamation? The calling code does not use/reference an object beyond the single loop.

Comment: Oh, I accepted this answer. However there is a slight difference: an IQueryable is used in the example, not an *IEnumerable* (as what might be returned from an API) - does the same effect hold in both cases? Following up in the specific would make it even more robust/relevant.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the declared type of the variable, the runtime type matters. If the `IEnumerable<T>` comes from EF, such as in the sample code you provide, then the results above hold.

Comment: I believe that is incorrect in general wrt IQueryable and IEnumerable. Compare: `ef.Foos.Where(..).Count()` vs. `((IEnumerable<Foo>)ef.Foos.Where(..)).Count()`. In the former case the Count will be turned into the SQL; in the latter the SQL will only contain the filter AFAIK. Is there a potential of a similar issue here?

Comment: For applying LINQ operators the type matters because LINQ operators are extension method and their resolution happens based on the type of the variable. Iteration is an instance method and thus depends on the runtime object